# Android: move imageView thats lay on window manager with animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-animation, android-windowmanager

a have some problem and didn't find a solution. The problem is, i have a image view that's lay on layout and this layout lay on window manager, this image view is clickable. This image view have to move to right and to the left and be clickable. Here is my code

`public class FloatingAnimationService extends Service {

```
private WindowManager windowManager;

private ImageView floatingUnit;

private boolean isClicked;

public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();

    isClicked = false;

    floatingUnit = new ImageView(this);
    //a unit as imageView
    Picasso.with(this).load(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/" + "cat.png")).into(floatingUnit);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(AppMethods.getPxFromDp(120 ,this), AppMethods.getPxFromDp(120 , this));
    floatingUnit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    final LinearLayout floatingUnitLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    floatingUnitLayout.addView(floatingUnit);

    windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    //here is all the science of params

    final LayoutParams myParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    myParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    myParams.x=0;
    myParams.y=100;


    windowManager.addView(floatingUnitLayout, myParams);



    // add a floatingUnit icon in window

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this ,R.anim.floating_unit_animation);



    floatingUnit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startQuestion();
            stopSelf();
            windowManager.removeViewImmediate(floatingUnitLayout);
            isClicked = true;

        }
    });
    floatingUnit.startAnimation(animation);
    startAnimationTimer(floatingUnitLayout);

    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    myParams.x = 100;
    myParams.y = 100;
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatingUnitLayout, myParams);

    Animation animationToRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this ,R.anim.left_to_right_animation);
    Animation animationToLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this , R.anim.right_to_left_animation);

    animationSet.addAnimation(animationToRight);

    floatingUnit.startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

private void startQuestion (){

    Intent intentQuestionActivity = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
    intentQuestionActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intentQuestionActivity);

}

private void startAnimationTimer(final View floatingUnitLayout){


    long animationLifeTime = 10000;
    new CountDownTimer(animationLifeTime, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("animation remaining: " , Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("animation: " , "DONE");
            if(!isClicked) {
                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(floatingUnitLayout);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }.start();


}
```

`
Please help. Thanks !

Comment: But what is the problem ?

Comment: Problem is that i can't move imageView to the right of the screen and make it clickable

Comment: Please add a screenshot of how it is displayed now. Or include all the code so we are able to test it ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all . Found the solution by myself. The trick is: to move a image that lay on window manager, you have to update the Layout Params.

here is the code below

```
 private void startAnimationTimer(final View floatingUnitLayout) {

    long animationLifeTime = AppData.first(AppData.class).getCountSecondsPicShow();
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(animationLifeTime, 100) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            Log.i("animation remaining: ", Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            myParams.x = myParams.x + 2;
            myParams.y = myParams.y + 2;
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatingUnitLayout, myParams);


        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("animation: ", "DONE");
            if (!isClicked) {

                windowManager.removeViewImmediate(floatingUnitLayout);
                stopSelf();
            }
        }
    }.start();


}
```